# Select option if same value is selected giving empty page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile select box and it has options. I have given a onchange function and once the value gets changed function gets called and values get's displayed. But when I select the same option which is currently selected the function is not getting called and I am getting an empty page.

```
<select name="select-custom-20" id="select-custom-20" data-native-menu="false" onchange="teamchange();">
        <option >Select a Team</option>
        <option value="team1">team1</option>
        <option value="team2">team2</option>
        <option value="team3">team3</option>
        <option value="team4">team4</option>
</select>
```

and this is my function

```
function teamchange(){
    var teamname = document.getElementById("select-custom-20").value;
    alert(teamname);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically if you select the same value, there is no change to trigger.  You can have an event handling the close of the of the popup:

```
$(document).on("popupafterclose", "#select-custom-20-listbox", function(){
    var teamname = $("#select-custom-20").val();
    alert("On Popup Close: " + teamname);        
});
```

jQM automatically creates a popup widget with an id of selectid + "-listbox", so in your example: select-custom-20-listbox. You can add a handler for the **[popupafterclose](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#event-afterclose)** event on this dynamically created popup.

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/zk9v29j4/)**

NOTE: if you have long list that does not fit the page, jQM creates a dialog page instead of a popup, so you would use the pagecontainer widget events instead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the probelm . I have removed data-native-menu="false" from the select option and everything works fine now .